# Remedy for Dry Chicken Yakhni pulao ?

Tags: indian-cuisine, texture

My question is that today I prepared Chicken Yakhni Pulao,it tasted good but it is very dry, i mean the youghurt and the masala got absorbed in the rice very much. And i have made lots of it, it is also fully cooked. So does anyone know how should i make the fully cooked pulao little juicy ? As it is difficult to eat the dry pulao(I may require another curry with it)

Comment: Please help us out by including the recipe you've used and the method you've used. It's impossible for us to know what to change if we don't know what you've done already.

Comment: Are you trying to make it better next time, or salvage what you've already made?

Answer (score 1):

Pulao is usually a "dry" dish without any gravy/sauce left in it when it finishes cooking. If the rice seems to be fully cooked and the individual grains do not seem to be under cooked or slightly crunchy then I think it is probably correct.

Many people serve raita (I like a simple yoghurt-onion-tomato mix with some chili powder and salt) and green coriander chutney along with pulao or biryani which helps to make the overall experience less dry. I usually cook the marinade as well to make a gravy/salan to serve on the side when I make chicken biryani.

Answer (score 0):

I recon it has formed like a cake after cooling. The best option you have is to take a big chunk of it in a microwaveable container (making sure that you are not breaking the rice grains) and sprinkling with some water. Then cover with a cling film and microwave for 3-4 minutes from cold. Your rice grains will separate because of the extra moisture from the sprinkled water and the Pulao will become slightly moist.

But yes, Pulao is a dry dish and needs to be eaten with a side like Raita or Salan.